# Track Install from Facebook SDK came from Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using facebook iOS ads to send install to my app.

I am using the following code to track the installs.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
    [FBSettings publishInstall:[FBSession defaultAppID]];
}
```

Is there anyway to track that a new install actually came from Facebook? I want to plug it into Flurry and track what quality of user I am getting.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to accomplish? I have used facebook mobile ads and reporting with the code you already have, and facebook tell me (on their portal) how many users installed the app after clicking on the app. What extra info are you trying to get?

Answer (score 6):

Typically when you track ad providers (be it facebook, greystripe, adcolony, etc) they will record some sort of device identifier for every device that clicks the ad. In the past it was UDID but moving forward Apple is pushing their advertiser identifier.

You will need to store your own list of identifiers for every device that installed your app and then cross reference with the list of devices that clicked on the advertisement.  The ad provider should be able to provide this list, including Facebook.

I am not sure if Flurry supports making cohorts by advertiser but I do know Kontagent has some admin tools which allow you to drop in reports from the ad networks to enable tracking by provider.  Alternatively you could always roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way.
You could check wether the user liked your Fanpage or stuff like that, but you don't know the link the user opening the AppStore came from.

A possibility could be to not directly link the ad to the AppsStore, but link it via a private proxy that recognizes a user clicked on the link and if shortly after this time a user downloaded your app it may be a Facebook User that clicked the Ad

Answer (score 0):

I figure you has read the SDK documentation.
If you go to *[Set up your app to measure mobile app install ads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/#u_0_7)* you can read that this information is stored in your  [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

In this [link](http://devsbuild.it/resources/type/article/measuring-facebook-mobile-app-install-ads) is explained clearly how the "app installs ads" works and how to manage this information.

Unfortunately isn't possible to export this information directly from your app to be sent to Flurry.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is attributing the source of installs for a mobile advertising campaign. In order to do this, you need to be able to determine that the person who installed the app was the same person that clicked on the relevant ad (on Facebook, or whatever other ad provider). In order to do this, you need an identifier that uniquely identifies the user--in the past this was the UDID, now it's moving towards the advertising identifier.

Many ad providers will calculate this figure for you if you report to them whenever a use installs the app for any reason, by comparing all the identifiers of the installs you send them with the identifiers of the users that clicked their ads.